# Why am I getting a "cannot set property of undefined" when writing to an array generated by a replit.db call?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, replit, replit-database

This was marked duplicate for some reason. I didn't even know what the thing in the other post was called.

So, my problem is that this replitdb call below (not sure if thats what it's called) somehow sets the `users` array to `{"undefined":{"online":false,"clearance":0}}`

```js
var users = {}
db.list().then(keys => {
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    db.get(keys[i]).then(value => {
      if (value == null) return
      users[keys[i]] = {online:null,clearance:null}
      users[keys[i]].online = false
      users[keys[i]].clearance = value.clearance // value.clearance is a number between 0 and 5
      
    })
  }
})
```

This code, again, sets the `users` array to `{"undefined":{"online":false,"clearance":0}}` which throws an error when trying to write to a different value that isn't "`undefined`". The following lines are the lines that cause errors by attempting to write to `users[user]`.

```js
  socket.on('userDisconnect', (user) => {
    users[user].online = false // user is a string
  })
  
  socket.on('userConnect', (user) => {
    users[user].online = true // user is a string
  })
```

And the error caused from line 260 or when a user attempts to connect to the server is the following:

```js
TypeError: Cannot set property 'online' of undefined
```

What is going on here, and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ah, a classic gotcha.

Comment: yes that question you sent (autodeleted???) was helpful and fixed the problem